# Creating a sign-up page on power apps and sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint-online, powerapp

I want to create a signup page and in all demonstrations, I've seen the user has to be added before they can login. I want a way that allows users to be added on sharepoint when they first sign-up.

[image: On the picture I first had to add the username and password]